# How can I automatically display info as slider is moved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I am learning objective C and am stuck on the final part of my task. In the test app, I am comparing the amount of alcohol in two different drinks.

Currently, I can move the slider and press "Calculate" and it will display the amount of alochol in drink 1 and it's  equivalent in drink 2. (i.e. 3 beers is contains as much alcohol as 2 glasses of wine).

I need to be able to display data as I move the slider instead of pressing calculate. I was able to figure out how to display the numbers as I pull the slider but could not find any resources on auto-updating data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#import "BLCViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *beerPercentTextField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *beerCountSlider;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;

//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *valueLabel;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)sender {
    NSString *enteredText = sender.text;
    float enteredNumber = [enteredText floatValue];

    if (enteredNumber == 0) {
        // The user typed 0, or something that's not a number, so clear the field
        sender.text = nil;
    }

}

- (IBAction)sliderValueDidChange:(UISlider *)sender {
    //NSLog(@"Slider value changed to %f", sender.value);
    //[self.beerPercentTextField resignFirstResponder];

    //When slider value changes, the code below is executed
  NSString *sliderValue =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.beerCountSlider.value];
    self.beerPercentTextField.text = sliderValue;


    }


- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.beerPercentTextField resignFirstResponder];

    // first, calculate how much alcohol is in all those beers...

    int numberOfBeers = self.beerCountSlider.value;
    int ouncesInOneBeerGlass = 12;  //assume they are 12oz beer bottles

    float alcoholPercentageOfBeer = [self.beerPercentTextField.text floatValue] / 100;
    float ouncesOfAlcoholPerBeer = ouncesInOneBeerGlass * alcoholPercentageOfBeer;
    float ouncesOfAlcoholTotal = ouncesOfAlcoholPerBeer * numberOfBeers;

    // now, calculate the equivalent amount of wine...

    float ouncesInOneWineGlass = 5;  // wine glasses are usually 5oz
    float alcoholPercentageOfWine = 0.13;  // 13% is average

    float ouncesOfAlcoholPerWineGlass = ouncesInOneWineGlass * alcoholPercentageOfWine;
    float numberOfWineGlassesForEquivalentAlcoholAmount = ouncesOfAlcoholTotal / ouncesOfAlcoholPerWineGlass;

    // decide whether to use "beer"/"beers" and "glass"/"glasses"

    NSString *beerText;

    if (numberOfBeers == 1) {
        beerText = NSLocalizedString(@"beer", @"singular beer");
    } else {
        beerText = NSLocalizedString(@"beers", @"plural of beer");
    }

    NSString *wineText;

    if (numberOfWineGlassesForEquivalentAlcoholAmount == 1) {
        wineText = NSLocalizedString(@"glass", @"singular glass");
    } else {
        wineText = NSLocalizedString(@"glasses", @"plural of glass");
    }

    // generate the result text, and display it on the label

    NSString *resultText = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%d %@ contains as much alcohol as %.1f %@ of wine.", nil), numberOfBeers, beerText, numberOfWineGlassesForEquivalentAlcoholAmount, wineText];
    self.resultLabel.text = resultText;

}

- (IBAction)tapGestureDidFire:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self.beerPercentTextField resignFirstResponder];

}

@end
```

Comment: You're already updating one `UILabel` in `sliderValueDidChange:`.  How do you think you would update two labels?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just call `[self buttonPressed:nil]` when your slider value updates. It's not the cleanest solution but it should work.

Comment: A better approach is to take the code from `buttonPressed` and put it in another method that can be called from both `IBAction` methods

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. I was on my iPad when I answered this so I kept it short.